# Mysql - Select the closest min value if the specified value doesn't exists

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table containing multiple same element with different build numbers. What I am trying is if specified build doesn't exists, system will return the mimimum closest build value for each element separately. If build exists, it will simply show it.

Example table;

| Name | Build |
| --- | --- |
| App1 | 1 |
| App2 | 2 |
| App1 | 3 |
| App1 | 4 |
| App2 | 5 |
| App3 | 10 |
| App3 | 11 |

For instance;

> Scenarios for only App1, App2

**Scenario 1** : User searches for build `3` :

- `App1` should return `3` and `App2` should return `2` instead of
  empty result or vice versa;

User searches for build `2` :

- `App2` should return `2` and `App1` should return `1`

**Scenario 2** : Both `name` doesn't have the build number user specifies, it should return the closest `build` of each;

User searches for build `6` :

- `App1` should return `4` and `App2` should return `5`

***--EDIT--***

> Scenario for App1, App2, App3

**Scenario 3** : Some of the `name` has the exact or less `build` specified but the other `name` has bigger `build` than user search. Then it should return the lowest first of high.

User searches for build `9` :

- `App1` should return `4` and `App2` should return `5` and `App3` should return `10`

I tried several ways of achieving this but all I got is nothing. Is it possible to achieve with single query or do I need multiple query?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be a straight forward query.

```
select max(Build), Name from test
where Build<= 6       
group by Name
```

for the 2nd scenario.

```
with cte as (
 select max(Build) as build, Name from test
 where Build<= 6      
 group by Name )
select * from cte
union 
select max(Build), Name from test where Name not in (select Name from cte)
group by Name
```

try this [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d3d47db1c30cd2ca8118d341fa052af9)

Comment: try this https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d3d47db1c30cd2ca8118d341fa052af9

Comment: Thank you very much @ed-bangga! I just needed to change `max(Build)` to `min(Build)` for `scenario 3` on line 7.